# Successfully importing URLs from Access to ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, import, ms-access, url

I have an access database (2013 .accdb) with a column containing URLs. This field uses the hyperlink data type in access. I made an OLE connection to the database in ArcMap 10.3.1 but the URLs come in as BLOBs, which I understand Arc does if the data type length is over 255. 
Is there another data type I should use? Is there another work around? I want my URLs to display in the attribute table.
So far I have tried to convert the datatype to Short Text in Access, but this adds a # to the beginning and end of the URL which makes it less simple to copy paste the URL.

Comment: Instead of converting that data type, have you tried to bring the data into ArcMap, add a field with a data type of 'Text' (string) then just populate that new field with the URL links with the Field Calculator?